# Rxjs using Observable.from() string and prevent Observable being created many times

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

I have the following function that I'm trying to prevent Observable from being created every time this function is called. Basically, this function is called every time the user types something in the search field. I know I can create Observable from the event as Observable.fromEvent('button', click) but it would require me make tons of changes to the app. Any help is appreciated.

```
function search(input) { 
  Observable.from([input])
  .map(value => value)
  .filter(value => value.length >3)
  .debounceTime(300)
  .distinctUntilChanged()
  .switchMap(searchValue => { 
    //ajax call 
    return Promise.resolve(data) 
  }) 
  .subscribe(data => {
    //Do something with the data
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use observables, but don't want to create one from an event, you can create a `Subject` and can call its `next` method from within your `search`:

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';

var searchSubject = new Subject();
  .filter(value => value.length > 3)
  .debounceTime(300)
  .distinctUntilChanged()
  .switchMap(searchValue => { 
    // ajax call
    return Promise.resolve(data) 
  }) 
  .subscribe(data => {
    // Do something with the data
  });

function search(input) { 
  searchSubject.next(input);
}
```

Comment: I like the idea but once I add `map`, `filter`, etc to the subject, I don't get the stream in `subscribe` down below.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, but I've added the required imports to the answer, in case that was the issue. Also, the `map` was redundant - it did nothing - I'd not paid much attention to that, I just copied your composed observable.

Comment: Yeah, it is working now. I forgot to import `filter`, `debounceTime`, etc. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I also didn't understand the difference between `Observable` and `Subject`. Here is a good article that explains it in detail. https://medium.com/@benlesh/on-the-subject-of-subjects-in-rxjs-2b08b7198b93#.iol7sxhhf